Virtual Machine getting disconnected automatically in azure
I have tried multiple times creating azure virtual machine choosing windows OS
but it is getting auto disconnected with message "Your session has been ended please contact your administrator"
If some has faced similar problem please let me know what could be missing


Hello Vaibhav, to narrow down the root cause, can you try login into the VM from the azure portal itself? instead of rdping from your local machine, try the connect option and choose choose bastion. Reason behind it is want to understand if this is actually rdp issue i.e. due to a misconfigured RDP Listener or related to misconfig of NSG rules associated with the VM allow RDP traffic (port 3389) both inbound and outbound. If all these are good, then try using a different instance other than Standard B1s which is quite limited in resources.

MS says- The minimum size required to run Windows Server 2022 Datacenter Azure Edition in an Azure VM depends on the workload and performance requirements. However, the recommended minimum size for Windows Server 2022 Datacenter Azure Edition is the B2ms size, which has 2 vCPUs, 8 GiB of memory, and a temporary disk of 16 GiB , as per MS advice when I use a higher size basically the next size after B1s.
Just additional things you need to ensure- RDP port 3389 must be open. In your local machine rdp setting enabled

Microsoft server software support for Azure virtual machines

Get started with Windows Server Datacenter: Azure Edition
Sizes for Virtual Machines


I even tried with your exact same config, it connects but crashes. Try with B2ms and let me know if you are still facing issue.

Changing machine size Standard DS1 v2 (1 vcpu, 3.5 GiB memory) resolved the issue , I can confirm , thank you

Great!! I will post the same as answer.

As discussed in comments, MS says- The minimum size required to run Windows Server 2022 Datacenter Azure Edition in an Azure VM depends on the workload and performance requirements. However, the recommended minimum size for Windows Server 2022 Datacenter Azure Edition is the B2ms size, which has 2 vCPUs, 8 GiB of memory, and a temporary disk of 16 GiB
Just to ensure we are in sync, sharing with you the VM setup first, using the exact same config as yours.


Rest monitoring etc, your personal choice. I skipped those.
Now if you see, the VM is up, and I should be able to login / rdp into the VM using the public ip provided

connecting, but crashing due to resource crunch


Now again, as per MS advice when I use a higher size basically the next size after B1s.


See now it is working

It works for different size as well as you changed machine size Standard DS1 v2 (1 vcpu, 3.5 GiB memory) andit resolved the issue
Just additional things you need to ensure-
RDP port 3389 must be open.
In your local machine rdp setting must be enabled

You can even connect from the portal

References:

Microsoft server software support for Azure virtual machines
Get started with Windows Server Datacenter: Azure Edition
Sizes for Virtual Machines

